# jQuery select input within a td for all rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to calculate the values with all the input fields within a table upon change.
Here is the sample HTML table targeted and also the jQuery code I am trying to use to get the values from all input fields in the table by iterating over the rows using `foreach`:

```js
$('#mytable :input').change(function() {
  var numrows = 1;
  var rows;
  $('#out').text('');
  $('#mytable tr').each(function() {
    var date = $(this).children('td:eq(1)');
    var obj = $(this).children('td:eq(2):input').value;
    var comma = $('#queryTable tbody tr').length != numrows ? "," : "]";
    var row = "{\"" + date + "\";\"" + obj + "\"}" + comma + "\n";
    //row += date * obj;
    //row =  numrows == 1 ? "["+row : row;
    $('#out').append(row);
    numrows++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="out">
Test
</div>

<table id="mytable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <th>Col3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Label1:
      <Input type="text"></Input>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Label2:
      <Input type="text"></Input>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value3</td>
    <td>ttt</td>
    <td>Label3:
      <Input type="text"></Input>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZYD4/882/)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. You should post a definite question, as well as things you've tried, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: You could use `$('#mytable').find('input')` to get all of the inputs directly then use the `.each` to run the calculation.

Comment: I needed row by to do calculation. @LPZadkiel gave me what I was looking for, thanks all.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i recomend you to use keyup instead of change because the change will not trigger till the input lost focus:

```
$('#mytable :input').keyup(function(){
  var numrows = 1;
  var rows;
  $('#out').text('');
  $('#mytable tr:not(:first-child)').each(function(){
      var date = $(this).children().eq(1).text();
      var obj = $(this).children().eq(2).children('input').val();
      var comma = $('#queryTable tbody tr').length != numrows ? "," : "]";
      var row = "{\""+date+"\";\""+obj+"\"}"+comma+"\n";
      //row += date * obj;
      //row =  numrows == 1 ? "["+row : row;
    $('#out').append(row);
      numrows++;
  });
});
```

here is your working jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZYD4/891/

btw i ignore the first row adding this to the selector `:not(:first-child)` because that is the header row

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you. I have updated my fiddle to my need:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZZYD4/901/